# UV Map Faces Unwrapping Out Of Order

Tags: uv

I have an issue where my faces are unwrapping out of order (it would seem).

I've selected all my faces and unwrapped them, but there is ONE face that seems out of order during texture mapping.

**You can see the circle that doesn't complete properly**.

I have this issue often. Is there something I can do to sort the faces?

[image]

Comment: from what's visible, it seems that th rightmost "circled" face is overlapped to another one, maybe? because a slice of the blue circle seems to be missing, but could it be "covered" by that lst face?... difficult to say, only from the above images

Comment: Could it be the result of a boolean operation on a cylinder?

Comment: I don't know... it is really difficult from just those picture above. Could you pack the texture and upload it (or that part only) to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your Q and add the provided link, maybe?

Comment: It would be easier to help him if suted uploads the part of his file that he is showing, his image is not very clear and it is difficult to guess the problem because it does not show a wider context of it, nor does it explain what it is (a silindro a cube, a divided plane)?, I have given a couple of examples, these are based on what I assume from what I am seeing, if it is not what I need to indicate it and explain a little more within your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select in your UV map, the UV corresponding to the part of the circle that is cut and accommodate it correctly, whether it is on top of another UV or that is rotated in another direction, I gave you an example, but you must apply it according to your trouble

[image]

You should also scale your Uv map according to the width and coverage of its texture, remember to leave a minimum of 20 pixels, to prevent the game engine or rendering, have problems detecting the vordes and cause spots or cuts on the shore of the texture of your model

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to use the line select tool and scale up more so it covers the whole image, But Im not too shure :D

Comment: Scaling isn't the problem. Look at the circle and how it's mapping on the surface. It's missing a face on the right side. Not sure if it has to do with the "always selected" face during UV map editing. :(

Comment: oh I see are you able to scale forward or backwards to see if it helps?

Comment: Scaling just seems to move the error around as long as the Circle lands in the middle (where it needs to be). What's odd is that the mesh in the UV map looks perfect. As I select the faces in edit mode, the proper face selects in the UV map. I'm slightly confused, because I have the concave version on the other side, and it works perfectly.

Comment: yes I am slightly Confused too this is why I hate messing with UV's